# If I scan the ETH blockchain, how do I know if the ETH addresses belong to ERC-20-compliant wallets?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet

If I scan the ETH blockchain, how do I know if the scanned ETH addresses belong to ERC-20-compliant wallets?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as an "ERC-20 compliant wallet". If you have the private key to an address, then you can use ERC-20 tokens with it. Nobody should use a wallet that they don't have the private key to, either, as ownership of funds in a wallet is defined by whether or not you have the private key to it.

Comment: To expand on this: you wallet is simply and interface (usually) like in the case of MEW or Jaxx. Your account on the blockchain can hold tokens. Whether or not you can see them is the only difference your wallet choice makes.